# Sally found an excuse and escaped the punishment. Can I replace the word 'escaped' by 'ran away, fled or got off'?

Tags: word-usage

Sally found an excuse and escaped the punishment. Can I replace the word 'escaped' by 'ran away, fled or got off'?

If 'escaped the punishment' is a set collocation？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Thought up a good/clever excuse" sounds a bit more idiomatic than "found an excuse."

Then, "escaped the punishment" could be replaced by "got off". However, that is very casual speech, not formal writing, and the listener ought to already understand the details of the situation.

With "fled" and "ran away", you may actually picture a person literally running. That doesn't fit this situation. Sally has avoided punishment. "Avoid" is not "run".

To "escape a punishment" isn't precisely a set phrase. Yes, the words do go together very well. But so do many others: "watching the TV", "reading a book", etc. Those are just normal words, rather than a fixed collocation.